# Adding directive depending on scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've a array in a scope of a controller like

```
$scope.data = [{
   "name" : "test",
   "type" : "test"
 },{
   "name" : "production",
   "type" : "production"
 }]
```

Now in the view I'm executing a loop on the model data and I've two directive one is test another is production. I want to show those directive within the ng-repeat depending on the type. So I've written

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
  <test ng-if="item.type == 'test'"></test>
  <production ng-if="item.type == 'production'"></production>   
</div>
```

This thing works fine.But my question is, instead of adding these ng-if is there any better way out so that I can add these directives in the dom depending on the type value of the model. I tried like:

```
<{{item.type}}></{{item.type}}>
```

But obviously it didn't worked.

Comment: There is another way: create third directive :)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ePpflWfOtqfDjWSS1b2e?p=preview

Comment: @K.Toress : That was great really helpful. But now I've a problem. I want to pass the item to the directive like <test widget=item></test>, but after making the directive dynamic using $compile I can't write var html = '<'+item.type+' widget=item></'+item.type+'>'; It's not working in that case.

Comment: @K.Toress I mean what if I want to show the "name" value of the model from the directive by I don't want to access the whole array from the directive.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to have a unique directive with a scope data you can use as condition:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
  <directive data-env="item.type" data-name="item.name"></directive>
</div>
```

In the directive you can use the `$scope.env` to do conditional stuff and displaying only what you need.

Comment: Actually the requirement is that the directives should be independent. I mean Different developer will work on different directive and then finally we need to integrate all the directives in a single view depending on the type.